# PHP opposite of .=

Tags: php

Does anyone know if there is an opposite to `.=`
Eg:

```
$a = "B";
$a .= "C";
```

results in $a having a value of "BC", but is there something like:

```
$a = "B";
$a =. "A";
```

to result in `$a` having a value of `"AB"`?

Comment: `substr()` with `strpos()`

Comment: The `$a = 'A' . $a`. I don't know other shorter construct.

Comment: @Brad I'm not sure you did read the question or just only the title...2

Comment: I think such an operator would only lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: @WouterJ, I did read the question... I misunderstood.  Tim, why would you want this?  There is no purpose for such an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no converse. Not every operation in PHP will have a shortcut notation. Sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and write it out long-hand.

```
$a = 'B' . $a
```

Answer (score 7):

You mean like this?

```
$a = "B";

$a = "A" . $a; //result "AB"
```

Comment: That doesn't technically address the question; this uses two operators, OP is looking for one operator, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, this technically addresses the question; not logically. It gives an alternate to the non-existent solution.

Comment: Thanks for response but I was trying to find a short code while typing code so my example might be too specific and this solution would involve:             $sometimesnecessarylongvariablename = "A" . $sometimesnecessarylongvariablename ;

Comment: @TimHigham Just create a function then.

Answer (score 1):

`=.` doesn't exist in PHP. Do the following instead:

```
$a = 'B';
$a = 'A' . $a;
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question No there is no reverse prepend concatenation operation in php. See the manual on strings, here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php
"The first is the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments. The second is the concatenating assignment operator ('.='), which appends the argument on the right side to the argument on the left side".

If however you do want to prepend look at the other example answers, or otherwise you can use another version of it:

```
$a = "B";
$a = "A{$a}"; //inserts value of variable 'a' in position 2.
```

Test code : http://codepad.org/VDqM4MlL

Comment: While previous answers are good, this looks great.

Comment: tested at http://codepad.org/jLO2esBs

Comment: If it don't exist this is logically the closest so will vote this as an answer unless anyone disagrees ??????